# i am trying to compile below code with dummy class

Tags: c++, casting, operator-keyword

```
class A
{
public:

};

class B
{
  public:
  operator A()
  {
   // code here
  }
};


int main ()
{
  A foo;
  B bar;
  foo=bar;
}
```

i am proceeding with this idea , that bar will typecast into A which will be assigned to foo as due to by default assignment operator in class A,
but i receive error no proper conversion exist.

Comment: The whole program and your concept about **typecasting** is wrong is wrong. Please **research** about the subject before you ask a question.

Comment: Class are **user defined** objects. They can't be **typecasted**.And **operator** is to overload an **operator** for an **object** of user defined **class**. Not as a **constructor**.

Comment: i am typecasting object of class.......

Comment: please explain it further

Comment: default **data types** like int ,double,char,float,etc can be type casted because that is provided/included by/in compiler. But unexpected user defined object can't be typecasted as the compiler is not designed to take it. It gets very complicated it you want to write a code to typecast **n** number different object defined by **n** number of users.

Comment: i need your email id............i want to discuss further issue